# ¿Como modificar una imagen por medio de PHP que esta guardado en la BD con URL?

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando en android studio en un modulo para subir imagen y su descripción, el cual ya tengo realizado la subida desde el formulario de la app sin problemas mediante un servidor remoto y de ahí se guardan a la base de datos con su respectivo URL, y estoy en el siguiente proceso de modificar esa imagen pero no se modifica nada.

**registroImagen.php**

```
<?php

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   include('conexion.php');

   $imagen = $_POST["imagenMexico"];
   $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];


   $path = "uploads/$nombre.png";

   $actualpath ="https://upstream-responses.000webhostapp.com/$path";

   $query = "INSERT INTO t_imagen_estado_mexico(imagenMexico,nombre)
   VALUES('$actualpath','$nombre')";
   $result = $mysql->query($query);

  if ($result) {
  file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($imagen))
  
  echo "1";

 } else {
  echo "2";
}
$mysql->close();
}
?>
```

**updateImagen.php**

En este archivo no se si algo este mal codificado

```
<?php

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  include('conexion.php');

  $idmexico = $_POST["idmexico"];
  $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
  $imagen = $_POST["imagenMexico"];


  $path = "uploads/$nombre.png";

  $actualpath ="https://upstream-responses.000webhostapp.com/$path";

  $query = "UPDATE t_imagen_estado_mexico SET nombre = '$nombre', imagenMexico = '$actualpath'
  WHERE idmexico = '$idmexico'";
  $result = $mysql->query($query);

  if ($result) {
  file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($imagen));
 
  echo "1";

  } else {
  echo "2";
  }
  $mysql->close();
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: que error te marca?

Comment: @Bryro no me marca ni un error nomas que en la base de datos no se me actualiza nada, pero en el servidor remoto si se sube la imagen.

Comment: en ves de `echo "2";` puedes hacer un `echo "error: ".$mysql->error;` para ver porque falla!

Comment: @Bryro no me marca ningún error, aquí tengo otra pregunta que a lo mejor esta mas entendible https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/518399/como-actualizar-una-imagen-en-la-base-de-datos-desde-android-studio