# ¿Como actualizar una imagen en la Base de Datos desde android studio?

Tags: php, java, android-studio

Estoy creando una app con android studio en una sección donde tengo que subir una imagen de rutas de evacuación sobre contingencia volcánica, ya tengo realizado la parte donde realizo el registro y se sube la imagen a un servidor remoto desde android y de ahi se guarda a la base de datos como tipo URL, el detalle es que quiero realizar un CRUD, el siguiente paso es modificar o editar el cual ya tengo los archivos realizados, pero el detalle que no actualiza nada en la base de datos, tal vez por el lado del servidor el archivo de php este algo mal.

**ModiPuntosEncuentroEM.java**

```
public class ModiPuntosEncuentroEM extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button BtnselecImagen, BtnguradarImagen;
ImageView imagen;
EditText ETNombre;
Bitmap bitmap;
String KEY_IMAGEN = "imagenMexico";
String KEY_NOMBRE = "nombre";
private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private static final String URL = "https://upstream-responses.000webhostapp.com/updateUbicacion.php";

private int position;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_modi_puntos_encuentro_e_m);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Modificar");

    BtnselecImagen = findViewById(R.id.btnBuscar2);
    BtnguradarImagen = findViewById(R.id.btnModificar2);
    ETNombre = findViewById(R.id.Editext2);
    imagen = findViewById(R.id.imagenView2);


    Intent intent =  getIntent();
    position = intent.getExtras().getInt("position");

    ETNombre.setText(Lista_UbicacionMex.estadoMexicoArrayList.get(position).getNombre());
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(Lista_UbicacionMex.estadoMexicoArrayList.get(position).getImagenMexico())
            .into(imagen);

    BtnselecImagen.setOnClickListener(this);
    BtnguradarImagen.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id== android.R.id.home){
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public String getStringImagen(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
private void uploadImage(){

    //Mostrar el diálogo de progreso
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Subiendo...","Espere por favor...",false,false);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            //Descartar el diálogo de progreso
            loading.dismiss();
            //Mostrando el mensaje de la respuesta
            if (response.equals("1")){
                Toast.makeText(ModiPuntosEncuentroEM.this,"La imagen se subio correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();

            } else if (response.equals("2")){
                Toast.makeText(ModiPuntosEncuentroEM.this, "Error al subir imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    //Descartar el diálogo de progreso
                    loading.dismiss();

                    //Showing toast
                    Toast.makeText(ModiPuntosEncuentroEM.this,volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            //Convertir bits a cadena
            String imagen = getStringImagen(bitmap);

            //Obtener el nombre de la imagen
            String nombre = ETNombre.getText().toString().trim();

            //Creación de parámetros
            Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            //Agregando de parámetros
            params.put(KEY_IMAGEN, imagen);
            params.put(KEY_NOMBRE, nombre);

            //Parámetros de retorno
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Creación de una cola de solicitudes
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Agregar solicitud a la cola
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Imagen"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            //Cómo obtener el mapa de bits de la Galería
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            //Configuración del mapa de bits en ImageView
            imagen.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == BtnselecImagen){
        showFileChooser();
    }

    if(v == BtnguradarImagen){
        uploadImage();
    }

}
}
```

**updateUbicacion.php**

```
<?php

 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
 include('conexion.php');

 $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
 $imagen = $_POST["imagenMexico"];

 $path = "uploads/$nombre.png";

 $actualpath ="https://upstream-responses.000webhostapp.com/$path";

 $query = "UPDATE t_imagen_estado_mexico SET nombre = '$nombre',imagenMexico = '$actualpath'
 WHERE nombre = '$nombre'";

 $result = $mysql->query($query);

 if ($result) {
 file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($imagen));

 echo "1";

 } else {
 echo "2";
}
$mysql->close();
}
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**carpeta Uploads donde se guardan las imágenes**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**base de datos**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es que esta enviando `nombre` para cambiar y eso al ser reemplazado por el nuevo valor no lo encuentra cuando haces el update. Deberías hacer algo como lo que te dejaré

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo lo voy a verificar tal como mencionas gracias.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo gracias por el apoyo, pero ya logre arreglar ese detalle con el parámetro idmexico, ya que ese no se modifica, tal como mencionas el parámetro nombre no se realiza el update por ese motivo que se cambia el valor.

Comment: Perfecto, recuerda que puedes añadir tu respuesta y marcarla como correcta para poder dar cierre a esta pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifique mi consulta de la siguiente manera y con esto se me arreglo el problema.

```
  $query = "UPDATE t_imagen_estado_mexico SET idmexico = '$idmexico', nombre =  '$nombreNuevo', imagenMexico = '$actualpath'
  WHERE idmexico = '$idmexico'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero, crear dos variables en php:

```
$nombreViejo = $_POST["nombreViejo"];
$nombreNuevo = $_POST["nombreNuevo"];
```

Y modificas tu consulta así:

```
$query = "UPDATE t_imagen_estado_mexico SET nombre = '$nombreNuevo',imagenMexico = '$actualpath'
 WHERE nombre = '$nombreViejo'";
```

En tu nueva actividad, recibes el valor del nombre viejo:

```
String nombreViejo = getIntent().getExtraString("nombreImagenViejo");
```

Y tu `Request` quedaría así:

```
String nombreNuevo = ETNombre.getText().toString().trim();

//Agregando de parámetros
params.put(KEY_IMAGEN, imagen);
params.put("nombreViejo", nombreViejo);
params.put("nombreNuevo", nombreNuevo);
```

Comment: a que te refieres con nueva actividad

Comment: Por lo que se ve en tu GIF, al presionar la imagen se despliega un AlertDialog que muestra dos opciones. Dentro de ellas, está la opción modificar, al presionarla se inicia o se abre tu nueva actividad donde editas la imagen con su nombre. Desde la actividad donde muestras la imagen envías el nombre por medio del intent a la nueva actividad y aquí la recibes como muestro en mi respuesta